# Not able to save PDFs from Excel/VBA on one computer

Tags: vba, excel, pdf, outlook

I recently received help here for an Excel spreadsheet we have that allows users to create quotations for customers. The spreadsheet uses VBA to allow the user to press a button which generates a PDF out from certain sheets, and attaches them to a new Outlook email.

Unfortunately this isn't working on one of the user's computers. The problem seems to be with the generating of the PDF. Initially when pressing the button, nothing happened. I suspected it was to do with the Microsoft Add-in to Save as PDF, so I made sure it was installed, which it was. After 'commenting out' the error message coming from the code to get to the real error message from Visual Basic, I found it to be this:

```
run-time error '-2147467261 (80004003)': Document not saved.
```

When clicking 'Debug' it highlights:

```
FileName = Create_PDF_Sheet_Level_Names(NamedRange:="addtopdf1", _
                                        FixedFilePathName:=ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & "Quotation - " & Range("G18") & ".pdf", _
                                        OverwriteIfFileExist:=True, _
                                        OpenPDFAfterPublish:=False)
```

Which relates to:

```
Function Create_PDF_Sheet_Level_Names(NamedRange As String, FixedFilePathName As String, _
                                      OverwriteIfFileExist As Boolean, OpenPDFAfterPublish As Boolean) As String
'This function will create a PDF with every sheet with
'a sheet level name variable <NamedRange> in it
    Dim FileFormatstr As String
    Dim Fname As Variant
    Dim Ash As Worksheet
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    Dim ShArr() As String
    Dim s As Long
    Dim SheetLevelName As Name

    'Test If the Microsoft Add-in is installed
    If Dir(Environ("commonprogramfiles") & "\Microsoft Shared\OFFICE" _
         & Format(Val(Application.Version), "00") & "\EXP_PDF.DLL") <> "" Then

        'We fill the Array with sheets with the sheet level name variable
        For Each sh In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
            If sh.Visible = -1 Then
                Set SheetLevelName = Nothing
                On Error Resume Next
                Set SheetLevelName = sh.Names(NamedRange)
                On Error GoTo 0
                If Not SheetLevelName Is Nothing Then
                    s = s + 1
                    ReDim Preserve ShArr(1 To s)
                    ShArr(s) = sh.Name
                End If
            End If
        Next sh

        'We exit the function If there are no sheets with
        'a sheet level name variable named <NamedRange>
        If s = 0 Then Exit Function

        If FixedFilePathName = "" Then

            'Open the GetSaveAsFilename dialog to enter a file name for the pdf
            FileFormatstr = "PDF Files (*.pdf), *.pdf"
            Fname = Application.GetSaveAsFilename("", filefilter:=FileFormatstr, _
                                                  Title:="Create PDF")

            'If you cancel this dialog Exit the function
            If Fname = False Then Exit Function
        Else
            Fname = FixedFilePathName
        End If


        'If OverwriteIfFileExist = False we test if the PDF
        'already exist in the folder and Exit the function if that is True
        If OverwriteIfFileExist = False Then
            If Dir(Fname) <> "" Then Exit Function
        End If

        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        Application.EnableEvents = False

        'Remember the ActiveSheet
        Set Ash = ActiveSheet

        'Select the sheets with the sheet level name in it
        Sheets(ShArr).Select

        'Now the file name is correct we Publish to PDF
        On Error Resume Next
        ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat _
                Type:=xlTypePDF, _
                FileName:=Fname, _
                Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
                IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
                IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
                OpenAfterPublish:=OpenPDFAfterPublish
        On Error GoTo 0

        'If Publish is Ok the function will return the file name
        If Dir(Fname) <> "" Then
            Create_PDF_Sheet_Level_Names = Fname
        End If

        Ash.Select

        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
        Application.EnableEvents = True
    End If
End Function
```

I'm really scratching my head here! Checked all settings side-by-side with my machine on Excel and Outlook, including Trust Centre settings. Also checked add-ins.

Comment: Have you tried commenting out the `On Error Resume Next` ?  It's odd that the debugger highlights the function call and not the actual problem

Comment: Had a similar problem when workbook wasn't saved to local drive or not saved at all.  Check the value of `ThisWorkbook.Path` and verify it's not empty.

Answer (score 0):

1. Please check if there is enough disk space where the user wants to save the PDF file to!
2. I would recommend to check the length of the PDF fullname (path, filename and file extension; in your example it is the variable "Fname") as well before calling "ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat(...)", because filenames (or rather fullnames) under Microsoft Windows regularly cannot exceed more than 255 characters (see: [Naming Files, Paths, and Namespaces](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365247%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)).